# mongdb find user in time slot

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
[
 {
    id:1,
    name:tapos,
    booked: [
        {
            order_id:5,
            start_date:2019-04-14 22:10:00.000,
            end_date:2019-04-15 01:10:00.000,

        }
    ]
 },
 {
    id:2,
    name:sanjib,
    booked: [
        {
            order_id:6,
            start_date:2019-04-15 22:10:00.000,
            end_date:2019-04-15 23:10:00.000,

        }
    ]
 }
]
```

its my mongodb user table i need to get user who is free 2019-04-14 10:00:00 to
2019-04-14 11:00:00 this time slot. I am trying but can not write this query appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. If it is not working please let me know

db.test.aggregate([{$addFields: {startDate1: {$dateFromString:{dateString:  "$booked. startDate"}},endDate1: { $dateFromString: {dateString:  "$booked.endDate"}}}}, {$match: { startDate1: { $lte: ISODate('2018-12-29T00:00:00.000Z') },endDate1: { $gte: ISODate('2018-12-29T00:00:00.000Z') }}}]).pretty().
Pass your input to above.
May be it is date format issue. And also you try with iso date function.

Comment: this query return null